# How to map dynamic json value to HashMap in Pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

i use jackson for jax-rs handler

the json member is always same, only 1 of it member have dynamic value ..

this dynamic value could only be "" or json object

**json possibility 1**

```
{
    "event":"test",
    "eventInfo": ""
}
```

**json possibility 2**

```
    {
        "event" : "test",
        "eventInfo" : {
             "name" : "abc",
             "last" : "def"
         }
    }
```

eventInfo value could only be "" or json

i try to map this json to MyBean.java

**MyBean.java**

```
public class MyBean{

    private String event;
    private Map<String, String> eventInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map getEventInfo() {
        return eventInfo;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setEventInfo(String name, String value) {
        this.eventInfo.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

the mapping process happen in MyService.java

**MyService.java**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String receiveClientStatus(MyBean status){

    if(!status.getEventInfo().isEmpty()){
        String last = status.getEventInfo().get("last").toString() ;
        System.err.println( last );         
    }


    return "ok";
}
```

jackson fail convert the json as show above to MyBean.java

How to do this?

forgive my english

thanks

Comment: The method setEventInfo accepts string value. Should it be Object?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov i already try it as Object but its also fail too

Comment: The MyBean looks ok. How are you calling the receiveClientStatus? From a browser?

Comment: @skarist i use JQuery POST, also application/json as contentType, i think there's no problem for sending the JSON, i also check my json in json validation online too. the json i send is similiar with two example i show. i think the problem is jackson can't convert my json to MyBean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the `setEventInfo()` method of MyBean object. In one case the value assigned to it is empty which is treated as string in other case its a linked hashmap. So modify the argument to accept Object. like

```
class MyBean {

    private String event;
    private Map<String, String> eventInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map getEventInfo() {
        return eventInfo;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setEventInfo(Object eventObject) {
        if(eventObject instanceof Map){
            this.eventInfo.putAll((Map<String, String>) eventObject);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBean [event=" + event + ", eventInfo=" + eventInfo + "]";
    }
}
```

Now it should work. Eg

```
String json1 = "{ \"event\":\"test\", \"eventInfo\": \"\" }";
String json2 = "{\"event\":\"test\",\"eventInfo\":{\"name\":\"abc\",\"last\":\"def\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    MyBean bean1 = mapper.readValue(json1, MyBean.class);
    System.out.println(bean1);
    MyBean bean2 = mapper.readValue(json2, MyBean.class);
    System.out.println(bean2);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```